# Nativescript gradle project-level

Tags: android, gradle, nativescript

I want to use Segment (with Firebase) into my NativeScript app. So I must follow this instructions : https://segment.com/docs/destinations/firebase but I must modify two files : the Module-level build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Add these lines
        compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.+'
        compile 'com.segment.analytics.android.integrations:firebase:+'
    }
}

// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and the Project-level build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Add this line
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

But with NativeScript I have only one build.gradle. So, how can I implement this lines in gradle ?

Thanks !

Comment: Any dependencies you want to add, you could add it to `build.gradle` in your project level.

Comment: If I try to put both in the same build.gradle file, I have an error (`Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`). I tried in a native Android project to put everything in the level project build.gradle but I have the same error

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but they may help someone in the future. Nativescript Docs aren't the best and this worked for me so it MAY not work for you. 
This applies for Plugins and Regular Apps.

**Buildscript Gradle**.

1. `App_Resources/Android/buildscript.gradle`
2. **PLUGINS** `buildscript.gradle`

```
repositories {
    // Add this line
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

**App Grade**

1. **PLUGINS** `include.gradle`
2. `App_Resources/Android/app.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.+'
    compile 'com.segment.analytics.android.integrations:firebase:+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

HOWEVER

> The compile configuration still exists but should not be used as it will not offer the guarantees that the api and implementation configurations provide.https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html

You can also write this as 
**App Grade**

1. **PLUGINS** `include.gradle`
2. `App_Resources/Android/app.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.+'
    implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android.integrations:firebase:+'
}
```